# Using insertAfter option on random divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

JS:

```
(function animate() {
    $("#houses div:first").each(function(){
        $(this).animate({marginLeft:-$(this).outerWidth(true)},1000,'linear',function(){
            $(this).insertAfter("#houses div:last");
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
            animate();
        });
    });
})();
```

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/DDUK6/10/)

It works. When slide to left my divs, get new div. But it's ordered. I want, get random divs.

How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you want to get random div's when they are sliding out in order?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you...

Comment: You want the slider to get random divs or to rename the value in the div?

Comment: Yes @C.S. I want slider to get random divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem but picking random div will break the animation of other div.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDUK6/12/)**

```
   (function animate() {
    $("#houses div:first").each(function(){
        $(this).animate({marginLeft:-$(this).outerWidth(true)},1000,'linear',function(){
            $(this).insertAfter("#houses div:nth-child("+getRandomInt(1,9)+")");
            $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
            animate();
        });
    });
})();

function getRandomInt (min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want get random div on only last child.

Comment: That is what code does. It is not going to give you smooth effect because you are picking random div from one which are getting animated.